# Why is my EventHandler only grabbing the last item in the array?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, addeventlistener

This is a generate table function that generates a table of sites with a corresponding "X" button [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPYwn.png)

I've created an EventHandler for the dynamically created buttons. However, I can only grab the last item in the array. When I print out i, it's always the last index--no matter what button I press.

```
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var site = array[i];
  console.log(site);

  //create cell & cell text for WEBSITE
  var cellWebsite = document.createElement("td");
  var website = document.createTextNode(array[i]);

  //append cell text to cell, then cell to row (like setting a "stage")
  cellWebsite.appendChild(website);
  row.appendChild(cellWebsite);

  //create a cell & cell text for BUTTON
  var cellDelete = document.createElement("td");
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON"); //has its own element
  var text = document.createTextNode("x");
  button.appendChild(text);
  cellDelete.appendChild(button);
  row.appendChild(cellDelete);

  //event listener for the X button, runs deleteSite function
  //with the site text passed through it

  button.addEventListener('click', function(event)
  {
    deleteSite(site);
    console.log("deleted  : " +site);
  });
```

The array is an array of strings. Not sure how to make sure that the button that is being clicked corresponds to the correct index in the array. How can I change my function?

Comment: What is `length`

Comment: most likely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Probably easiest is to use another loop: `for(const site in array) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Thanks everyone! I just used "let" instead of "var" when I declared my i, and that fixed it. (I believe it changes the scope of i)